# How to get Ember component object inside promise success or error call back?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have pass two callback function success and error on promise returned from ajax call using then method. Now i am unable to get Ember component object inside success/error method.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    data:null,
    issueType:'',
    description:null,
    prepareSubmitRaiseIssueModal:function(){
        var data = this.get('data');
        this.set('ticket.category',data.category);
        this.set('ticket.name',this.get('session.currentUser.first_name'));
        this.set('ticket.phone',this.get('session.currentUser.phone'));
        this.set('ticket.groupId',data.groupId);
        this.set('ticket.ownerId',this.get('session.currentUser.id'));
        this.set('ticket.oyoId',this.get('session.currentOwnerHotelOyoId'));
        this.set('ticket.ticketRaisedBy','owner');
        this.set('ticket.bookingId',data.bookingId);
        this.set('ticket.subType',data.subType);
        this.set('ticket.subSubIssue',data.subSubIssue);
        this.set('ticket.email',this.get('ticket.oyoId')+'@oyoproperties.com');
        this.set('ticket.subject',this.get('ticket.oyoId')+' : '+this.get('ticket.category'));
        this.set('ticket.description',this.get('description'));
    },
    success:function(){
        console.log(this.get('description'));
    },
    error:function(){
        console.log(this.get('description'));
    },
    actions :{
        submitIssue:function(){
            this.prepareSubmitRaiseIssueModal();
            this.get('ticket').submitRaiseIssue().then(this.success,this.error);
            //this.send('closeRaiseIssueModal');
        },
        closeRaiseIssueModal:function(){
            this.sendAction('closeRaiseIssueModal');
        }
    }
});
```

i am able to get Ember component object if instead of passing named function i pass anonymous function.

```
submitIssue:function(){
            var self = this;
            this.prepareSubmitRaiseIssueModal();
            this.get('ticket').submitRaiseIssue().then(function(response){
                console.log(self.get('description'));
            },
            function(err){
                console.log(self.get('description'));
            });
            //this.send('closeRaiseIssueModal');
        },
```

is there any way i can get the Ember component object's reference for former case??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow speaking of a spaghetti.

```
prepareSubmitRaiseIssueModal:function(){
        var data = this.get('data');
        this.set('ticket.category',data.category);
        this.set('ticket.name',this.get('session.currentUser.first_name'));
        this.set('ticket.phone',this.get('session.currentUser.phone'));
        this.set('ticket.groupId',data.groupId);
        this.set('ticket.ownerId',this.get('session.currentUser.id'));
        this.set('ticket.oyoId',this.get('session.currentOwnerHotelOyoId'));
        this.set('ticket.ticketRaisedBy','owner');
        this.set('ticket.bookingId',data.bookingId);
        this.set('ticket.subType',data.subType);
        this.set('ticket.subSubIssue',data.subSubIssue);
        this.set('ticket.email',this.get('ticket.oyoId')+'@oyoproperties.com');
        this.set('ticket.subject',this.get('ticket.oyoId')+' : '+this.get('ticket.category'));
        this.set('ticket.description',this.get('description'));
    },
```

How about

```
prepareSubmitRaiseIssueModal:function(){
        var data = this.get('data');
        var ticket = this.get('ticket')
        ticket.setProperties({
           'category': data.category,
           'name': ...
        })

    },
```

And to pass reference's you can either use

```
promise.then(function() {
     this.mysuccess();
}.bind(this), function() {
     this.myerror();
}.bind(this))
```

---

```
const self = this; 
promise.then(function() { 
    self.blah();
});
```

---

```
promise.then(result => { 
    this.blah();
})
```

In your case I would write a utility JS file for displaying notifications.

And handle success for each promise personally and let errors be handled in a general error method.

*utils/notifications.js*

```
function reportError(error) {
    displayNotification('error', getErrorMessage(error));
}
```

---

```
import reportError from 'utils/notifications';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
....
promise.then(result => {
   // Do custom stuff with result;
}, reportError);
....
});
```

And promise within a promise

```
return promise1.then(x => {
   return promise2.then(x2 => {
       return promise3 ... etc
   })
}).catch(reportError); // Single hook needed but u need to return promises
```